# Calling Servlet from HTML

Tags: html, servlets, seo

i want to call servlet everytime when an html page is loaded.In other words HTML page calls a servlet link automatically not via form.

For this am using below meta tag in html page,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://zerocool:8080/practice/WelcomeServlet?123">
```

Now when a user visits HTML page he gets redirected to servlet,and this servlet after analyzing the user redirects him back to the original HTML URL or someother URL depending upon valid and invalid user.

Now my question is,by adding above meta tag will the website be punished by google search engine or not in terms of SEO/ranking as user is redirected twice,1st to servlet and second back to html page.But all this happen very fast.

OR 
You can suggest some alternate way to call servlet.
Actually servlet will be monitoring cookie in users browser to validate user

Comment: Why not use AJAX and avoid redirect-hell?

Comment: Client is using basic HTML..Like Blogger

Answer (score 0):

This way it is likely to end up in an infinitive loop which is extreme annoying for the user.

You should either use Ajax or apply an redesign. You can't protect a html page against users while allowing google to view it.

ONe way to protect pages is FIRST to check whether an user is logged in and if so show the protected page, otherwise collecting authorization data.

Comment: loop wont be infinite,if code is well written and tested.

Am not saying that google should not be redirected,am just asking that if google bot is redirected twice 1st to servlet and again back to website,will it impact search ranking of website in any way?